# String and substring - Arduino, esp32

Tags: arduino, esp32

What am I doing wrong with 
`line = client.readStringUntil('\r');`
and 
`if (line.substring(0) == "1");`

```
 // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()){
  line = client.readStringUntil('\r'); //    String
    Serial.println(line); 
  }

// Rele 1

  if (line.substring(0) == "1") 
 {
    Serial.println("Rele 1 ON");
    digitalWrite(Rele_1, LOW);
    myBr1 = 1;
 }
 else if (line.substring(0) == "0") 
 {
    Serial.println("Rele 1 OFF");
    digitalWrite(Rele_1, HIGH);
    myBr1 = 0;
 }
 else
 {
    Serial.println("Rele 1 OFF the charts - Check what you give me....");
    digitalWrite(Rele_1, HIGH);
    myBr1 = 0;
 }
```

When I run this code, serial printline gives me: 000
but Relay 1 gives me: Rele 1 OFF the charts - Check what you give me....
If I force 
`line=001;`
Serial print gives me 1 back, not 001
I have 2 relays now and a bit to start OTA update. Will be adding more relays.
What am I mixing up, and how do i correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned the diffrence between '0' and "0" and 0 today.
By changing:

```
  if (line.substring(0) == "1") 
 {
```

To

```
 if (line.charAt(1) == '1')   // Bryter 1. 
    {
```

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your test, you should do force line="001" with the quotes to be a string, not an int. This is why it prints 1 and not 001

For the usage of `line.substring(0) == "1"`, line.substring(0) will return "001" not "1". The correct way to do would be `line.substring(0,1) == "1"` to only read the first character.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. You pointed me in the right direction. I have now learned that there is a difference between 8 "8" and '8'